# Authenticate HTTP request with Alamofire (swift 3)

Tags: ios, json, swift, authentication, alamofire

How do I make HTTP request with authentication? In my first class I ask a user to login

```
       let url = "https://api.sis.kemoke.net/auth/login"
var parameters = ["email": "", "password": ""]
var token = ["X-Auth-Token": ""]

// Parameters textfields
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField?

// A method for the login button
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    parameters["email"] = email?.text //Read email from text field
    parameters["password"] = password?.text //Read password from text field
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: token).responseJSON {
        (response) in
        print(response.response?.statusCode as Any)


        //Reading JWT authentication token from the server
        if let tokenString = response.result.value as? String {
            self.token["X-Auth-Token"] = tokenString
        }

        // manage alerts for different status codes
        if response.response?.statusCode == 401 {
            // present alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "OOPS!", message: "Either username or password is wrong!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: nil)
        } else if (self.email?.text?.isEmpty)! || (self.password?.text?.isEmpty)! {
            let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "HEY!", message: "You need to enter something!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

After user enters correct credentials I segue to the screen where user can pick an option.
In this case when user taps on "courses" button it segues to the tableView which should display courses specific to that user.

```
struct Courses {
    let course : String

    init(dictionary: [String:String]) {
        self.course = dictionary["course"] ?? ""
    }
}
   func downloadData() {
         Alamofire.request("https://api.sis.kemoke.net/student/course").responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        //Optional binding to handle exceptions
        self.courseData.removeAll() // clean the data source array
        if let json = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] {
            for course in json {
                self.courseData.append(Courses(dictionary: course))
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

And than I load the data into an array.
The problem is that I get the following error in the console

```
  Optional(https://api.sis.kemoke.net/student/course)
  Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000228fc0> { URL:        https://api.sis.kemoke.net/student/course } { status code: 401, headers {
 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Accept, Origin, Content-type, X- Auth-Token";
"Access-Control-Allow-Method" = "Get, Post, Put, Delete, Options";
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Sun, 08 Jan 2017 20:31:21 GMT";
Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
"Set-Cookie" = "__NCTRACE=aff38563-adcb-457d-a592-9f61b255bcbe; path=/;  expires=Sun, 08-Jan-2017 21:01:21 GMT; HttpOnly";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
 } })
Optional(12 bytes)
FAILURE
```

I get this error because I do not authenticate.
I could use Alamofier's authenticate method but it works only if I manually initialize variables (email and password(.
So how can I use already logged in user's token to get the relevant courses?